# view won't redraw

Tags: android, window, redraw

when a user selects a menu option, I catch it in onMenuItemSelected and then call

findViewById(R.id.xyz).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

But the view doesn't become visible.  I tried all kinds of things to force a redraw, but it just won't redraw.

ideas?

Comment: oh - forgot to mention, when I try to do this, I always get the warning:  06-26 18:11:19.511: WARN/InputMethodManagerService(208): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@2b39a3e8

Answer (score 0):

Possibly casting it to whatever type of object it is, such as if it were a button:

```
((Button)findViewById(R.id.xyz)).setVisisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

I know I would try that and even :

```
Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.xyz);
b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

However it might have something to do with your Z-order. You might be drawing them in a weird way so it is being drawn, but simply beneath another view? Keep us posted, and I'm sure you'll find the solution!